# How to effectively store data of varying time framces

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a form that captures production data for a certain process. When a employee enters production numbers, currently I am not sure what the time frame for the production numbers are.

E.g. Employee A enters a production number of 50 on 2017/10/02. This 50 represents the production of 1 day (2017/10/01). Now, employee B enters 550 on 2017/10/03, but this represents production for the week of 2017/09/24 to 2017/10/01.

Now, we know that various employees will be providing data of different time frames, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage this. I capture data using a Excel sheet with VBA, and then transfer it to a SQL database. Currently, in the database we use GROUP BY to get all data related to a certain month. So if the timestamp of the data is in September, all September data will be summed and the total used as the September total to date. However, this does not answer two key points:

1. If data for September is entered in October.
2. If data is entered that duplicates a period for the employee that was entered earlier.

What is the best way of managing this? I can change my capturing form and the way we manage data in the database.

## EDIT and more information:

The information I want to capture consists of production numbers from various production areas entered by an employee. So for example, site A will have 3 sub-sites. These sub-sites will each have a production achieved, target for the period and forecasted production number.

```
Timestamp:    Site:    Sub-site:    Production:    Target:    Forecast:    
2017/10/01    PlaceA   Line1        200            250        230
```

Comment: Can you outline what information you want to capture?

Comment: I would start by asking the employee the start and end dates of the production number. However, since one of your examples spans two months it is obvious you cannot easily get data for one month using a basic query.